# The column name CATALOGNO is not valid. SQL server exception

Tags: sql-server

I have a JAVA method that executes the following query to SQL server database

```
SELECT  [CHEMICAL_NAME],
        [CHEMI_UNIT],
        [PRICE],
        [VENDOR],
        [CATEGORY]
FROM [RPS].[dbo].[Chemicals]
WHERE CATALOGNO = '" + catNo+"' ;";
```

Following are the column names of the database table

```
CATALOGNO,
CAS_NO,
CHEMICAL_NAME,
CHEMI_UNIT,
PRICE,
VENDOR,
CATEGORY,
```

I get the above mentioned error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name
>   CATALOGNO is not valid.

The query by itself executes perfectly fine when I run it from SQL server query window.

Comment: The query you've given above not only contains an obvious syntax error (no space between the table name and the WHERE keyword), it's apparently part of a quoted string. Please show the entire line of code, if you're concatenating a SQL string - the problem probably lies in the concatenation. What you've provided above won't run as given.

Answer (score 0):

try to use full-qualified column name:

```
SELECT [CHEMICAL_NAME],[CHEMI_UNIT],[PRICE],[VENDOR],[CATEGORY]FROM [RPS].[dbo].[Chemicals]where [RPS].[dbo].[Chemicals].[CATALOGNO] = '" + catNo+"' ;";
```

But I'm not sure it helps...

Comment: Thanks , but same issue still persists

Comment: Well, I figured out the issue. My mistake. I was getting the catalog no from the result set. But I had removed it from the SELECT statement. So the resultset returned did not have the catalog no and so it threw an exception.